# Usages of Null / Nothing / Unit in Scala

Tags: scala

I've just read: http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2008/08/20/a-post-about-nothing/

As far as I understand, `Null` is a trait and its only instance is `null`.

When a method takes a Null argument, then we can only pass it a `Null` reference or `null` directly, but not any other reference, even if it is null (`nullString: String = null` for example).

I just wonder in which cases using this `Null` trait could be useful.
There is also the Nothing trait for which I don't really see any more examples.

---

I don't really understand either what is the difference between using Nothing and Unit as a return type, since both doesn't return any result, how to know which one to use when I have a method that performs logging for example?

---

Do you have usages of Unit / Null / Nothing as something else than a return type?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You only use Nothing if the method never returns (meaning it cannot complete normally by returning, it could throw an exception). Nothing is never instantiated and is there for the benefit of the type system (to quote James Iry: ["The reason Scala has a bottom type is tied to its ability to express variance in type parameters."](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/08/getting-to-bottom-of-nothing-at-all.html)). From the article you linked to:

> One other use of Nothing is as a return type for methods that never
>   return. It makes sense if you think about it. If a method’s return
>   type is Nothing, and there exists absolutely no instance of Nothing,
>   then such a method must never return.

Your logging method would return Unit. There is a value Unit so it can actually be returned. From the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Unit):

> Unit is a subtype of scala.AnyVal. There is only one value of type
>   Unit, (), and it is not represented by any object in the underlying
>   runtime system. A method with return type Unit is analogous to a Java
>   method which is declared void.

Comment: Thanks, by "never returns" do you mean that the call is blocking indefinitely (for exemple the startup method of job scheduler?)

Comment: @Sabastien: it doesn't return normally, it could throw an exception (see http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/08/getting-to-bottom-of-nothing-at-all.html). if the blocking call only ends with throwing an exception then that would count. thanks for the question, this needed clarifying.

Answer (score 19):

The article you quote can be misleading. The `Null` type is there for compatibility with the *Java virtual machine*, and Java in particular.

We must consider that *Scala*:

- is completely object oriented: every value is an object
- is strongly typed: every value must have a type
- needs to handle `null` references to access, for example, Java libraries and code

thus it becomes necessary to define a type for the `null` value, which is the `Null` trait, and has `null` as its only instance.

There is nothing especially useful in the `Null` type unless you're the type-system or you're developing on the compiler. In particular I can't see any sensible reason to define a `Null` type parameter for a method, since you can't pass anything but `null`

Comment: that's true, so in the end there is no other usage of Null?

Comment: @SebastienLorber edited the answer. I can't actually see any usage for the average developer. Maybe somebody else can think of something useful.

Comment: Thanks for this. If we know the reason for this kind of things, we understand them, otherwise we remember them.

Comment: Null is useful when you have a type parameter and may want to return null [like in this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336204/how-scala-generic-constraints-to-nullable-types-work), since your discouraged from using null in scala it rarely comes up though, there might be other usages in the type system as well

Answer (score 15):

> Do you have usages of Unit / Null / Nothing as something else than a
>   return type?

---

`Unit` can be used like this:

```
def execute(code: => Unit):Unit = {
  // do something before
  code
  // do something after
}
```

This allows you to pass in an arbitrary block of code to be executed.

---

`Null` might be used as a bottom type for any value that is nullable. An example is this:

```
implicit def zeroNull[B >: Null] =
    new Zero[B] { def apply = null }
```

---

`Nothing` is used in the definition of `None`

```
object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

This allows you to assign a `None` to any type of `Option` because `Nothing` 'extends' everything.

```
val x:Option[String] = None
```

Comment: Ok. For your usage of Unit you could have used a generic type so that the execute may return this generic type if your code block returns something else than unit.

Comment: As @drexin said in a comment on another answer, it's mostly used to denote a side effect.

Answer (score 6):

if you use `Nothing`, there is no things to do (include print console)
if you do something, use output type `Unit`

```
object Run extends App {
  //def sayHello(): Nothing = println("hello?")
  def sayHello(): Unit = println("hello?")
  sayHello()
}
```

... then how to use `Nothing`?

```
trait Option[E]
case class Some[E](value: E) extends Option[E]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

Comment: Also, `E` in the `Option` has to be in covariant position: `trait Option[+E]` to allow things like `val x: Option[Int] = None`

Answer (score 5):

I've never actually used the `Null` type, but you use `Unit`, where you would on java use `void`. `Nothing` is a special type, because as Nathan already mentioned, there can be no instance of `Nothing`. `Nothing` is a so called bottom-type, which means, that it is a sub-type of any other type. This (and the contravariant type parameter) is why you can prepend any value to `Nil` - which is a `List[Nothing]` - and the list will then be of this elements type. `None` also if of type `Option[Nothing]`. Every attempt to access the values inside such a container will throw an exception, because that it the only valid way to return from a method of type `Nothing`.

Comment: thanks I didn't know that None extends Option[Nothing]. It makes sense in some generics usage where a subtype could use Nothing (I guess it's hard to find an exemple for Null and Unit...)

Comment: Unit is used, where side effects occur, for example the IO monad can be of type `IO[Unit]` for printing to the console and the like.

Comment: Yes, never used the IO monad it makes sense to use it with Unit (and perhaps Nothing if it it is some IO operation that produces an infinite stream?)

Comment: No, Nothing makes no sense there.

Answer (score 3):

**Nothing** is often used implicitly. In the code below,
    `val b: Boolean =`
    `if (1 > 2) false`
    `else throw new RuntimeException("error")`
the **else** clause is of type **Nothing**, which is a subclass of Boolean (as well as any other AnyVal). Thus, the whole assignment is valid to the compiler, although the **else** clause does not really return anything.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of category theory **Nothing** is an **initial object** and **Unit** is a **terminal object**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects

**Initial objects** are also called **coterminal** or **universal**, and **terminal objects** are also called **final**.

If an object is both **initial** and **terminal**, it is called a **zero object** or **null** object.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of `Nothing` from `scala.predef`:

```
  def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError
```

In case you're unfamiliar (and search engines can't search on it) `???` is Scala's placeholder function for anything that hasn't been implemented yet. Just like Kotlin's `TODO`.

You can use the same trick when creating mock objects: override unused methods with a custom `notUsed` method. The advantage of not using `???` is that you won't get compile warnings for things you never intend to implement.