# Why doesn't Unit extend Product in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, tuples, case-class

In Scala, why doesn't `Unit` extend the `Product` trait just like the `Tuple`* classes and case classes (including the "empty" ones, like in `case class Empty()`, and case objects)?

`Unit` (the unit value `()` to be more specific) definitely stands as the empty product and tuple. It is used this way in [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), for example.

Comment: Can the down voter explain himself ?

Comment: You could read existing question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173477/usages-of-null-nothing-unit-in-scala before asking again .

Comment: @applicius - That question asks a different question and the answer for this question is not found in the answers for that question.  Can't you tell the difference?

Comment: @applicius I looked at the question you linked to, and agree with Rex Kerr, I'm just not asking the same question (and the answer to mine is not in your link).

Comment: There are 2 `Unit`s in Scala; which are you asking about? `Unit` written as a value (the companion object) is not a normal case object. It's not a `Unit` (the type, whose values are written `()`) or even a `BoxedUnit`, and can't be directly cast to either. Also, for your example of `case class Empty()`, the companion object `Empty` is not a `Product`, either.

Comment: @DanGetz I mean `()` that has type `Unit`, not the companion object. I want `val unit: Product = ()` to compile.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple. The `Unit` should be `Tuple0`, maybe its just a mistake of scala.

Comment: @DanGetz I'm not the one who rejected your edit. I took some parts of it into account. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unit is not analogous to to an empty collection, so it doesn't make sense to make it a product of arity zero.  Even though a Product0 wouldn't contain any data, it would still define behaviour via the productElement and productIterator methods.

The goal of Unit is to represent the absence of any behaviour or data beyond the bare minimum defined in Object.  In fact, the getClass() function returns null to indicate that it has no type, no by definition it should have no metadata associated with it.

If you were to make Unit extend Product, then it would violate the concept of "no type".

Comment: I don't know which version of scala you're using, but `().getClass()` does not return null in 2.11.2. `()` does have a type - `Unit` e.g. `val c: Class[Unit] = ().getClass()`.

Comment: Yes it does.  From the 2.11.2 sources:

final abstract class Unit private extends AnyVal {
  override def getClass(): Class[Unit] = null
}.

Or in a worksheet: ().getClass; res0: Class[Unit] = void

Comment: Despite that, `().getClass() == null` and `().getClass eq null` are both `false`, so that `void` you're seeing is different from `null`. As the comment above `class Unit` says, `()` "is not represented by any object in the underlying runtime system." It's treated specially.

Answer (score 0):

The current [Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html) seems to requires this in conforming implementations of Scala, according to section 12.2.3:

> Class `Unit` ... implements only the three methods equals, `hashCode`, and `toString` from class `Any`.

To extend `Product` and implement its methods, this part of the specification would have to change.

Comment: Of course, they could just change the specification, right? Can this question can be answered any better than "because they didn't do that"?