# scala.Null clarification

Tags: scala, null

Want to clarify about scala.Null. As I know scala.Null has instance null and class. For example if write like this

```
val x: Null = null
```

Type inference set type for the x Null.

According Scala classes hierarhy "please see image" Scala cannot use variables without wrappers like Int, Double, etc. That is why we can found Null for the type inference mechanism resolving. Is it correct vision ?

[Scala classes hierarhy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tujpT.jpg)

Comment: *That is why we can found Null for the type inference mechanism resolving.* You're question is vague. What does that sentence mean?

Comment: scala.Null for resolving type inference mechanism ? Why we cannot use null like Java ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing some of these concepts:

**Type Inference** is the ability of the compiler to *infer* the type when the code doesn't explicitly state it. In your example - you *do* state the type, and that type is Null - no inference here:

```
val x: Null = null
```

Here's a simple example of type inference:

```
scala> val whoKnows = 12
whoKnows: Int = 12
```

Compiler inferred the type `Int` since we assigned the value 12, which is an integer. There's much more to it (see http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference), but that's the basics.

**null** can be used in Scala **just like in Java** (although it's very much frowned upon, as Scala offers many safer alternatives, mainly `None`), for example:

```
scala> val nullStr: String = null
nullStr: String = null

scala> val nullList: List[Int] = null
nullList: List[Int] = null
```

Where *can't* null be used? Just like in Java - for "primitives" like int, double etc. In Scala, there's no such thing as a primitive, but there's still a difference between these "value" types (named with upper-case like other types, e.g. `Int`, `Double`) and other types: value types share the common trait `AnyVal`, whereas all other types share the trait `AnyRef` - to signify, among other things, this difference.

As for what the `Null` trait is good for - see [Usages of Null / Nothing / Unit in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173477/usages-of-null-nothing-unit-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

The type `Null` in Scala is a special type. What's special about it is that it is a subtype of all reference types - it's a subtype of every type that is a subtype of `AnyRef`.

The reason for that is to make it possible to assign the value `null` to any reference type.

Note that besides reference types, Scala also has value types. These are the types that are subtypes of `AnyVal`. Examples of value types are the built-in types that map to the primitive types of the JVM: `Byte`, `Short`, `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, `Boolean`, and `Char`, and also the type `Unit`.

Note that `AnyVal` and its subtypes are **not** subtypes of `AnyRef`. You can't assign `null` to a variable of a value type.

Note that the value types `Int`, `Double` etc. are **not** like Java's wrapper types (`java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Double` etc.). When you use the value types, there is no boxing and unboxing going on to/from objects. These value types directly map to the primitive types of the JVM. Therefore you cannot assign `null` to a variable of one of those types.

In other words: types like `Int` and `Double` are **not wrappers**, they directly represent primitive types.