# Understanding of scala.Nothing type

Tags: scala

According to the scala specification, 
scala.Nothing type - buttom for all types. 
Type "Nothing" exists but instance of Nothing does not exists.

How it works:

```
def ??? : Nothing = throw new NoImplementedError
def sys.error(message: String): Nothing = throw new RuntimeException()
def sys.exit(status: Int): Nothing = {...}
```

But in fact, all of mentioned methods return exception. Excepted `def sys.exit` Could you please clarify more about type Nothing. Any examples, explanations.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usages of Null / Nothing / Unit in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173477/usages-of-null-nothing-unit-in-scala)

Comment: A method which _returned_ an exception would look like `def foo = new RuntimeException`. If you gave it type signature `: Nothing`, it wouldn't compile, because it returns something.

Answer (score 7):

```
def ??? : Nothing = throw new NoImplementedError
```

does not return an exception, it throws an exception which is not the same thing. Exceptions are a control-flow mechanism which causes control to immediately jump to the nearest installed handler within the call stack. This means that in

```
val x = ???
```

`x` will never be assigned a value, so `x` can have any type at all. This type is `Nothing` in the scala type system which is the subtype of all types.

Non-termination also has type nothing since it also never returns a value e.g.

```
def loop(): Nothing = loop()

val x: Int = loop()
```

is therefore allowed since `x` will never be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala absolutely **everything** needs to have a return type.

`println` for example have the return type `Unit` because it's a unit of calculations that returns no value.

If everything needs to have a return type  then, how would you implement a function like `???`, so that it can be used by **any function**, **no matter what type** it needs to return?

Well that is what `Nothing` is for, it's a subtype of every other types (as `Any` is the top type of every other type), so a function that returns `Nothing` can be used anywhere and the type system will always stay consistent.

As you already noticed functions returning `Nothing` never return a value. That is because there is no value instenciable for `Nothing`.
You can see it as a way to make the compiler "happy" for functions that only throws or stop the app or loop forever.

---

In case you wonder why we don't use `Unit` instead of `Nothing`, here is an example:

```
def notYetImplemented: Unit = throw new Exception() 
def myFunc: String = notYetImplemented
```

This will not compile because `Unit` is not a `String` or a subtype of `String`. So you will need to do:

```
def myFunc: String = {
  notYetImplemented
  null
}
```

Which is not very convenient and for us to write a value to return even taught we will never reach this code.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, but in fact throw new RuntimeException() return exception instead of Nothing, correct ?

Comment: Throwing != returning.

Comment: @scala the type `Nothing` is a guaranty that it will never return something. Therfore the other options are throwing  an exception or terminating the app or looping for ever.

Comment: In Scala absolutely everything needs to have a return type. Even if it doesn't return something.