# Unit vs Nothing in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I'd like to clarify some details about `Unit` and `Nothing`.

For example:

```
def unit(companyId: Int): Unit = {}

def Nothing(companyId: Int): scala.Nothing = {}
```

According to the docs, `Unit` in Scala is very similar to `void` in `Java`. But

```
test("test Unit and Nothing") {
  println(unit(1))
}
```

- `Unit` return - `()`
- `Nothing` does not return anything.

Why does Scala has ***overflow*** type `Unit` which return `Nothing`?
Why Scala cannot use`Nothing` instead of `Unit`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usages of Null / Nothing / Unit in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173477/usages-of-null-nothing-unit-in-scala)

Comment: What do you mean by "overflow"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To show appreciations for your peers taking time to answer your questions please accept their answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 13):

`Unit` has cardinality 1. `Nothing` has cardinality 0.

Your second example

```
def Nothing(companyId: Int): scala.Nothing = {}
```

doesn't compile. It's impossible to return a `Nothing`, because `Nothing` has no inhabitants. Therefore a function that returns `Nothing` cannot return normally; it can only throw an exception.

```
def Nothing(companyId: Int): scala.Nothing = { throw new Exception(); }
```

Java's `Void` is comparable to `Unit` in that `Void` also has cardinality 1; its sole inhabitant is `null`. There is no type with cardinality 0 in Java (nor is it possible to define such a type), so Java does not have a type that is comparable to `Nothing`.
It is, of course, possible to write a Java method that always throws an exception, but it is not possible for the return type to express that.

---

Consider what happens when you use each of these in collections. For example, a `List[Unit]` can contain any number  of `Unit` values:

```
List()           : List[Unit]
List((), (), ()) : List[Unit]
```

whereas a `List[Nothing]` is necessarily empty, because there is nothing you can put into it.

```
List()           : List[Nothing]
```

The other important thing to note about `Nothing` is that it's a subtype of every other type. This makes sense, because it has no inhabitants; therefore every proposition ([propositions are closely related to types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOiZatlZtGU)) about `Nothing` instances holds vacuously. For an example of why this is useful, again consider lists:

```
List.empty[Nothing] : List[String]
```

Here we ascribe a `List[Nothing]` to the type `List[String]`, which we can do because `List`'s type parameter is covariant and `Nothing` is a subtype of `String`. Note that we couldn't do that with a `List[Unit]`, because `Unit` is *not* a subtype of `String`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I'm familiar with List[Nothing], Nil, Liskov substitution and so on. But my question is different. Why if function does not return data, need to use Unit and in fact return () instead of Nothing.

Comment: @scala Maybe this blogpost http://james-iry.blogspot.ch/2009/08/getting-to-bottom-of-nothing-at-all.html?m=1 might help giving you some additional intuition