# Scala Keywords Nothing,Null

Tags: scala

I was trying to understand some keywords in scala and I found these two keywords looks different in understanding.

What is Nothing Keyword in Scala. Can we create a instance for this?

Where is it useful?

Similarly in Scala, Null and null are same or different?

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is no `Nothing` keyword in Scala, nor is there a `Null` keyword in Scala. There is a `null` keyword in Scala, which denotes the `null` value, which is roughly similar to the `null` value in other languages with null references.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16173477/3248346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nothing` is a type and it is at the bottom of the Scala type hierarchy. What this means is that `Nothing` is a subtype of any other type. Also you cannot create instances of this type.

A well known example in the standard library is the type `Nil` which is really `List[Nothing]` under the hood.

`Null` is a type but `null` is an instance of the `Null` type.