# What is difference between Null, Nil and Nothing?

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and am a bit confounded by the difference between next types: 'Null', 'Nil' and 'Nothing'.

Can someone please help explain the difference to me?
From what i gather, "Nil" is used to describe an empty list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usages of Null / Nothing / Unit in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173477/usages-of-null-nothing-unit-in-scala)

Comment: Please refer to scala api as you first point of reference: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/

Comment: @Alex L, thank you for the link. But I am still confused as to what Nothing is exactly used for. And I guess how does it differentiate with None which according to the API represents non-existent values?....

Also in the linked thread, the Curcyu pointed out that Nothing is used when the function does nothing at all...  I don't really get the whole point of all the special subcategories of 'nothingness' and such.

Comment: broadly, your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173477/usages-of-null-nothing-unit-in-scala. if you have specific questions or doubts about specifics, consider opening one or more new questions about those specifics

Comment: Just like Seth said - make your question more specific to what exactly you struggle to understand. Put your comment into a question.

Comment: `Nil` is a *value*, the other two are *types*. That alone is an **extremely huge** difference between them.

Answer (score 14):

## Nothingness in Scala

There are 7 cases where you want to represent the concept of nothingness in Scala.

`Nil` - Used for representing empty lists, or collections of zero length. For sets you can use `Set.empty`

`None` - One of two subclasses of the Optional type, the other being `Some`. Very well supported by the Scala collections.

`Unit` - Equivalent to Java's `void` which is used for functions that don't have a return type

`Nothing` - A trait. It is a subtype of all other types, but supertype of nothing. It is like the leaf of a tree. No instances of Nothing.

`Null` - A trait. Not recommended to be used.

`null` - An instance of the trait, similarly used as the Java `Null`. Not recommended to be used.

## Best Practices

- If you have code that is returning null, change it to return an Optional.
- If you need to have an uninitialized variable, using Optional, or an empty list/collection instead of null
  *

For best practices recommendation, please see https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-null-values-option-uninitialized-variables

## Why is null so hated?

- Please watch [Tony Hoare's Billion Dollar Mistake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kz7DfbOuvOM)
- Null pointer errors are hard to debug

Answer (score 0):

In scala `null` is realy bad, you must use `Optional[T]`.

We have `Nil` which is a empty list to be able to do `1 :: Nil` to create a list that contain only `1`.

And, `Nothing` is a subtype of every type. In other world, is a object that represent `null`.

Comment: `Nothing` doesn't 'represent' null, there are no values of type `Nothing`.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's in the doc! Sorry for that. I mean I've never used it in Scala...

Comment: There's no `Optional[T]` in scala its `Option[T]`