# How to collect non-None values from a list of Option in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the best way to convert a list of `Option[T]` to a list of `T` where the option is not None?  E.g. I want to go from this:

```
scala> val xs = Some(3) :: None :: Some(4) :: Some(5) :: None :: Nil
xs: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(3), None, Some(4), Some(5), None)
```

to this:

```
List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)
```

in the most idiomatic way possible.

Answer (score 6):

You can just do `xs.flatten` The documentation is [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)

> Converts this list of traversable collections into a list formed by the elements of these traversable collections.

`Option` is a traversable type and it is biased so traversing the data structure will discard any `None` values

And fyi `null` and `None` are very different things. Your title isn't accurate

[What is difference between Null, Nil and Nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796032/what-is-difference-between-null-nil-and-nothing)