Can you declare a variable to be of type null?
In Scala, you can explicitly declare the type of a value to be "Null", such that you may only assign the value null to it:
scala> val myNull: Null = null
val myNull: Null = null

This means you can declare a function parameter such that you can know at compile time that you did in fact pass null to it!
def dontAskMeWhyYouWouldDoThis(mustBeNull: Null) = println("Hooray!")
dontAskMeWhyYouWouldDoThis(null)                        // prints "Hooray"
dontAskMeWhyYouWouldDoThis("this question is so silly") // compile error!

So my question is, does the null literal in Java have a type? Could you declare a variable to be of type "Null"?
Trying out Null in the REPL eliminates it as a potential option:
jshell> Null myNull = null;
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   class Null
|  Null myNull = null;
|  ^--^

While What is null in Java? answers "does null have a type", it does not in fact answer if and how to declare a variable of type "Null". (Edit: I am mistaken!)

I suppose you could write Void v = null;, but why would you want to do this?

The duplicate target clearly answers the question of how to declare a variable of the null type. Quote from the accepted answer there: "it is impossible to declare a variable of the null type"

It even answers the question if and how to declare a variable of type "Null": There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null, which has no name. Because the null type has no name, it is impossible to declare a variable of the null type or to cast to the null type.

For background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16174738/5772882. I can't see that it would be useful to name the type of null in Java.

For all the curious onlookers wondering, "why??", this is part of research I am doing for a talk about null and its history. I do not in fact have a need to declare a variable of type null.

You may declare enum Null { }. Since the enum hasn’t got any constants, the only possible value a variable of type Null can have is null (I still can’t see any use for it).
